# Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '?', expecting identifier (T_STRING)

Tags: php, laravel

Não consigo encontrar o erro nesse arquivo, o `debug` me mostra erro na linha 46, mais não encontro uma solução, alguma luz?

```
<?php

/*
 * This file is part of the Symfony package.
 *
 * (c) Fabien Potencier <fabien@symfony.com>
 *
 * For the full copyright and license information, please view the LICENSE
 * file that was distributed with this source code.
 */

namespace Symfony\Component\CssSelector\XPath\Extension;

use Symfony\Component\CssSelector\XPath\Translator;
use Symfony\Component\CssSelector\XPath\XPathExpr;

/**
 * XPath expression translator attribute extension.
 *
 * This component is a port of the Python cssselect library,
 * which is copyright Ian Bicking, @see https://github.com/SimonSapin/cssselect.
 *
 * @author Jean-François Simon <jeanfrancois.simon@sensiolabs.com>
 *
 * @internal
 */
class AttributeMatchingExtension extends AbstractExtension
{
    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function getAttributeMatchingTranslators()
    {
        return array(
            'exists' => array($this, 'translateExists'),
            '=' => array($this, 'translateEquals'),
            '~=' => array($this, 'translateIncludes'),
            '|=' => array($this, 'translateDashMatch'),
            '^=' => array($this, 'translatePrefixMatch'),
            '$=' => array($this, 'translateSuffixMatch'),
            '*=' => array($this, 'translateSubstringMatch'),
            '!=' => array($this, 'translateDifferent'),
        );
    }

    public function translateExists(XPathExpr $xpath, string $attribute, ?string $value): XPathExpr
    {
        return $xpath->addCondition($attribute);
    }

    public function translateEquals(XPathExpr $xpath, string $attribute, ?string $value): XPathExpr
    {
        return $xpath->addCondition(sprintf('%s = %s', $attribute, Translator::getXpathLiteral($value)));
    }

    public function translateIncludes(XPathExpr $xpath, string $attribute, ?string $value): XPathExpr
    {
        return $xpath->addCondition($value ? sprintf(
            '%1$s and contains(concat(\' \', normalize-space(%1$s), \' \'), %2$s)',
            $attribute,
            Translator::getXpathLiteral(' '.$value.' ')
        ) : '0');
    }

    public function translateDashMatch(XPathExpr $xpath, string $attribute, ?string $value): XPathExpr
    {
        return $xpath->addCondition(sprintf(
            '%1$s and (%1$s = %2$s or starts-with(%1$s, %3$s))',
            $attribute,
            Translator::getXpathLiteral($value),
            Translator::getXpathLiteral($value.'-')
        ));
    }

    public function translatePrefixMatch(XPathExpr $xpath, string $attribute, ?string $value): XPathExpr
    {
        return $xpath->addCondition($value ? sprintf(
            '%1$s and starts-with(%1$s, %2$s)',
            $attribute,
            Translator::getXpathLiteral($value)
        ) : '0');
    }

    public function translateSuffixMatch(XPathExpr $xpath, string $attribute, ?string $value): XPathExpr
    {
        return $xpath->addCondition($value ? sprintf(
            '%1$s and substring(%1$s, string-length(%1$s)-%2$s) = %3$s',
            $attribute,
            strlen($value) - 1,
            Translator::getXpathLiteral($value)
        ) : '0');
    }

    public function translateSubstringMatch(XPathExpr $xpath, string $attribute, ?string $value): XPathExpr
    {
        return $xpath->addCondition($value ? sprintf(
            '%1$s and contains(%1$s, %2$s)',
            $attribute,
            Translator::getXpathLiteral($value)
        ) : '0');
    }

    public function translateDifferent(XPathExpr $xpath, string $attribute, ?string $value): XPathExpr
    {
        return $xpath->addCondition(sprintf(
            $value ? 'not(%1$s) or %1$s != %2$s' : '%s != %s',
            $attribute,
            Translator::getXpathLiteral($value)
        ));
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function getName()
    {
        return 'attribute-matching';
    }
}
```

Comment: No método **translateExists** remove a interrogação do parâmetro **$value**, e verifique se a linha de erro muda. Eu não conheço essa notação de passagem de parâmetro com interrogação na frente desse cast direto.Existem mais em outros métodos abaixo.

Answer (score 4):

#### TL;DR

- O erro **não** está no método `translateExists` como informaram. O problema é que você está utilizando uma versão do `PHP` inferior à versão `7.1`

---

#### Sobre o erro

Desde a versão `7.0` do `PHP`, nós podemos utilizar os métodos da seguinte forma.

```
<?php

declare(strict_types=1);

class myClass
{
    public function imprimir(string $msg) : string
    {
        return $msg;
    }
}

$obj = new myClass;
echo $obj->imprimir("Hello World");
```

Esse `string $name` serve basicamente para forçar o desenvolvedor a passar uma variável do tipo `string`.

Caso você tente passar um `null`, por exemplo, receberá o erro `Fatal error: Uncaught TypeError: Argument 1 passed to myClass::imprimir() must be of the type string, null given`.

[**Demonstração**](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/b43b6f59be72e79ea40eab696a6c849180d7cf5b)

Porém muitos desenvolvedores acabaram tendo problema quando passavam um argumento do tipo `null` *(Muitas vezes os devs não faziam a validação antes)*.

Isso levou aos desenvolvedores do `PHP` a adicionar o operador `?` antes do tipo da variável para informar que aquele método, além de receber o tipo pré definido, também pode receber o valor de `null`.

Ou seja, a parti da versão `7.1` você pode utilizar o operador `?` e informar o parâmetro como `null` que você não receberá o erro acima.

```
<?php

declare(strict_types=1);

class myClass
{
    public function imprimir(?string $msg) : ?string
    {
        return $msg;
    }
}

$obj = new myClass;
echo $obj->imprimir(null);
```

[**Demonstração**](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/05409978160b33c83158ab3135acc74070b6b13f)

---

#### Formas de correção

Para corrigir isso você tem duas opções: Remover o operador `?` de **todos** os arquivos ou atualizar a versão do seu `PHP`.

Eu recomendo que você utilize a verão mais recente e estável do `PHP`. Além de melhorias você não precisará ficar removendo código toda vez que utilizar o `composer update`, por exemplo.

Imagina você ter que alterar isso em centenas de arquivos e a cada novo *update* do composer, ter que fazer a mesma coisa.

Comment: Obrigado @Valdeir, pelos esclarecimento, essa sintaxe é bem recente, não tinha o conhecimento dessas inovações. + 1 pela bela resposta!